# TIdTcpClient has shifted LastCmdResults

Tags: delphi, indy

I started implementing a system using a client server connection with a TIdCmdTcpServer and a TIdTcpClient.
The connection is established fine and communication seems to work in general, too. But LastCmdResults contains always the response of the command issued before the last command. It starts with an empty response for the TcpClient.Connect and then continues with a "welcome" as a response to the first TcpClient.SendCmd ('LIST'). When I issue the LIST command again I get the desired result but for the one before (tested with a counter variable).

Relevant Code Snippets:

Initialising  Command Handler

```
  CmdHandler := TCPCmdServer.CommandHandlers.Add;
  CmdHandler.Name := 'cmhList';
  CmdHandler.Command := 'LIST';
  CmdHandler.OnCommand := Cmd_ListDevices;
  CmdHandler.ExceptionReply.NumericCode := 550;
  CmdHandler.Disconnect := FALSE;

  TCPCmdServer.Active := TRUE;
```

Command handler event Cmd_ListDevices

```
procedure TSPM_Server.Cmd_ListDevices (aSender : TIdCommand);
begin
  aSender.Reply.SetReply (200, 'List');
  aSender.Reply.Text.Add ('Device 1');
  aSender.Reply.Text.Add ('Device 2');
  aSender.Reply.Text.Add ('Device 3');
  aSender.SendReply;
end;
```

Client Side

```
function TSPM_TCPClient.Connect (var aResponseText : string) : boolean;
begin
  TcpClient.Connect;
  aResponseText := TcpClient.LastCmdResult.Text.Text;
  result := TcpClient.Connected;
end;

function TSPM_TCPClient.RequestList (var aList : string) : integer;
begin
  aList := '';
  result := TcpClient.SendCmd ('LIST');
  if result = 200 then
    begin
      aList := 'CMD: ' + TcpClient.LastCmdResult.DisplayName + sLineBreak
                   + TcpClient.LastCmdResult.Text.Text;
    end;
end;
```

Anything obviously wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> LastCmdResults contains always the response of the command issued before the last command

That happens when you have the server setup to send a greeting when a new client connects (see the `TIdCmdTCPServer.Greeting` property), but your client code is not reading that greeting.  The greeting remains in the client's receive buffer until it is read.  So, the 1st `SendCmd()` will read the greeting, then the 2nd `SendCmd()` will read the response of the 1st `SendCmd()`, and so on.

After `TIdTCPClient.Connect()` is successful, call `TIdTCPClient.GetResponse()` immediately to read the greeting, `TIdTCPClient.Connect()` will not read it for you, eg:

```pascal
function TSPM_TCPClient.Connect (var aResponseText : string) : boolean;
begin
  TcpClient.Connect;
  try
    TcpClient.GetResponse(200); // <-- add this!
    aResponseText := TcpClient.LastCmdResult.Text.Text;
    Result := True;
  except
    TcpClient.Disconnect;
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Then you can call `TIdTCPClient.SendCmd()` afterwards as needed.

Comment: Thanks Remy! I suspected something like this by now, but was unsure what the "official" solution would be, as I didn't use Indy for a TCP server yet.